# Como descobrir o IP da LAN de um computador via HTML?

Tags: html

Preciso pegar o IP "local" de um computador via HTML, encontrei essa estrutura mas ele só me mostra o IP externo, alguem poderia me ajudar?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
    <title>Seu IP</title>
    <style>
        p, h1 {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
    <script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
  
    <script>
        /* Add "https://api.ipify.org?format=json" statement
           this will communicate with the ipify servers in
           order to retrieve the IP address $.getJSON will
           load JSON-encoded data from the server using a
           GET HTTP request */
  
        $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json",
                                          function(data) {
  
            // Setting text of element P with id gfg
            $("#gfg").html(data.ip);
        })
    </script>
</head>
  
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Seu endereço</h1>
        <h3>Public IP Address of user is:</h3>
  
        <p id="gfg"></p>
  
    </center>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Isso não é via HTML, mas sim **JavaScript**, usando a biblioteca **JQuery**, no seu código da pergunta.

Comment: e detalhe: JavaScript não tem acesso direto aos detalhes da rede local do usuario por razoes de segurança